# return CActiveDataProvider in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have 4 database table:

**User**: id, username, password

**Floor**: id, userid, name

**Room**: id, floor, name

**Student**: id, room, name, active

How to return CActiveDataProvider for the follow SQL command?

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student`.`active` = 0 AND `student`.`room` IN (SELECT `room`.`id` FROM `room` WHERE `room`.`floor` = (SELECT `floor`.`id` FROM `floor` WHERE `floor`.`userid` = $userid))
```

I tried:

```
$model = Student::model()->findAllBySql("SELECT * FROM student WHERE active = 0 AND room IN (SELECT id FROM room WHERE floor = (SELECT id FROM floor WHERE user = $user))");
return new CActiveDataProvider($model);
```

But response:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getDbCriteria() on a non-object in X:appserv\www\framework\web\CActiveDataProvider.php on line 225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named placeholder is useful.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'student.active = 0 AND student.room IN (SELECT room.id FROM room WHERE room.floor = (SELECT floor.id FROM floor WHERE floor.userid = :userid))';
$criteria->params=array(':userid'=>$userid);
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Student',array('criteria'=>$criteria,));
```

Comment: thanks you, but should edit $criteria->condition() to $criteria->condition=