# Fatal error: Call to a member function getDbCriteria() on a non-object

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15 and am getting this error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getDbCriteria() on a non-object`

the code below is in my view

```
  <?php
                        $model = new Comment(); //name of my model Project refers to Mysql innoDB table tblproject.
                        $daten=$model::model();
                        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($daten->with(array('posts' => array('limit'=>6)))->findAll());

                        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                            'itemView'=>'_view_latest_comment', //view file location
                        ));
                   ?>
```

the relation in my `comment.php` is as such

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, $this->module->userModelClass, 'userId'),
        'posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, "CommentsPosts", array("commentId" => "id"))           
    );
}
```

**UPDATE:**
i also tried this, but it does not set the limit to 5

```
$model = new Comment(); 
$daten=$model::model();
                    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                    $criteria->limit=5;

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($daten, array('criteria'=>$criteria));
```

when i `print_r($daten);` i get this

```
    Comment Object ( 
[_type:Comment:private] => 
[_key:Comment:private] => 
[_make:Comment:private] => 
[_model:Comment:private] => 
[_year:Comment:private] => 
[_new:Comment:private] => 
[_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) 
[_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) 
[_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
[_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 
[_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t 
[_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) 
[_validators:CModel:private] => 
[_scenario:CModel:private] => 
[_e:CComponent:private] => Array ( 
[onbeforesave] => CList Object ( 
[_d:CList:private] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[0] => CTimestampBehavior Object ( 
[createAttribute] => createDate 
[updateAttribute] => 
[setUpdateOnCreate] => 
[timestampExpression] => 
[_enabled:CBehavior:private] => 1 
[_owner:CBehavior:private] => Comment Object *RECURSION* 
[_e:CComponent:private] => 
[_m:CComponent:private] => ) 
[1] => beforeSave ) ) 
[_c:CList:private] => 1 
[_r:CList:private] => 
[_e:CComponent:private] => 
[_m:CComponent:private] => ) ) 
[_m:CComponent:private] => Array ( 
[commentable] => CommentableBehavior Object ( 
[mapTable] => 
[mapCommentColumn] => commentId 
[mapRelatedColumn] => 
[mapMakeColumn] => make_code 
[mapModelColumn] => model_code 
[mapYearColumn] => year_made 
[mapVariantColumn] => variant 
[_enabled:CBehavior:private] => 1 
[_owner:CBehavior:private] => Comment Object *RECURSION* 
[_e:CComponent:private] => 
[_m:CComponent:private] => ) 
[CTimestampBehavior] => CTimestampBehavior Object ( 
[createAttribute] => createDate 
[updateAttribute] => 
[setUpdateOnCreate] => 
[timestampExpression] => 
[_enabled:CBehavior:private] => 1 
[_owner:CBehavior:private] => Comment Object *RECURSION* 
[_e:CComponent:private] => 
[_m:CComponent:private] => ) ) 
[_new:CActiveRecord:private] => )
```

i'm trying to **dynamically** set a limit to the results returned, but can't seem to get it to work. any idea on what i'm doing wrong or missing? Thanks

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239758/return-cactivedataprovider-in-yii

Comment: @KirenSiva tried it. it doesnt set the limit, but no error this time. Updated question too

Comment: Where from is this getDbCriteria function called?

Comment: @PeterM page just dies, and it shows this `Fatal error: Call to a member function getDbCriteria() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/web/CActiveDataProvider.php on line 225`

Comment: @PratipGhosh i have no code that calls getDbCriteria. the only `getDbCriteria` found when i search thru my project is in `dev/common/lib/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php`

Comment: Then you need to debug in that script about how the object is initialized and how the getDbCriteria member function of that class is called.

Comment: This is a bit weird part: `$daten=$model::model();`, try `$daten=Comment::model();`. Check if `$daten` is instance of `CActiveRecord`.

Comment: @PeterM added the results of `print_r($daten);` to question

Comment: @PratipGhosh for my script to call the `getDbCriteria` member function, don't i have to do this 1st? `$criteria = new CDbCriteria;`

Answer (score 0):

Dataprovider require first parameter to be class name or model instance. In your view it's result of `findAll()`.

Move `with` clause to second parameter, something like that:

```
<?php
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(Comment::model(), array(
    'criteria' => array(
        'with' => array('posts')
)));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view_latest_comment', //view file location
));
```

**NOTE:** `CActiveDataProvider` will do `findAll` etc. by itself. It just need to know what need to be searched for.

Here is php doc part from `CActiveDataProvider` source:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
     'criteria'=>array(
          'condition'=>'status=1',
          'order'=>'create_time DESC',
          'with'=>array('author'),
     ),
     'countCriteria'=>array(
          'condition'=>'status=1',
          // 'order' and 'with' clauses have no meaning for the count query
     ),
     'pagination'=>array(
          'pageSize'=>20,
     ),
));
```

Comment: it still doesnt limit the output tho. is it because of the `self::HAS_MANY` relations? `$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(Comment::model(), array(
         'criteria' => array(
             'with' => array('posts'=> array('limit'=>2))
     )));`

Comment: That's whole different story, I recommend asking new question if you still have problems with limit. Maybe you have to put limit into `criteria` array? Generally, dataprovider set's limit/offset by itself, so this might be ovveriden by dataprovider.